# Cannot init an object in jquery document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an javascript object named `concept`:

```
function concept() {
    this.ConceptId = 0;
    this.Name = "";
}
```

I am trying to initiate it in jQuery `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var concept = new concept;
});
```

It returns an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: concept is not a constructor

If I move the object inside the `document.ready`, it is working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function concept() {
        this.ConceptId = 0;
        this.Name = "";
    }
    var concept = new concept;
});
```

I am still new on javascript, as far as I understood document.ready is run when DOM is completed. I don't understand why it cannot access the object which is defined out of the `document.ready` scope.

Here it is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49rkcaud/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're redefining `concept`. You just need to change the name of the variable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foo = new concept; // change the variable name here
    alert(foo.ConceptId); // = 0
});

function concept() {
    this.ConceptId = 0;
    this.Name = "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think execution of function is also necessary like `new concept()` or not?

Comment: Parentheses are optional when using the `new` keyword.

Comment: got it, appreciated also)

Comment: Why the downvote? Is a working example and explanation of the problem not enough?

Comment: And the other answer isn't even thought your answer explain the why. SO is sometimes strange...

Comment: @londondev no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3w284mcs/

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var concept = function() {
      this.ConceptId = 0;
      this.Name = "";
    }

    var concept_obj = new concept();
    alert(concept_obj.ConceptId);  
  });
```

Comment: I know this is working, but I don't want to define my concept object in the jquery scope as it is messy.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change `variable` name where call this function.

**Answer**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    /*function concept() {
            this.ConceptId = 0;
            this.Name = "";
          }*/

    var concept1 = new concept;
    alert(concept1.ConceptId);  
  });

  function concept() {
    this.ConceptId = 5;
    this.Name = "";
  }
```

**Better Approach**

You should create object of function using `()`

```
var objConcetp = new concept();
```

Also use `constructor` rather than directly assigning `values`. Your function look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var oConcept = new concept(1, "YourName");
});

function concept(conceptId, name){
   this.ConceptId = conceptId;
   this.Name = name;
}
```

Comment: 2 answers have solved the problem with good explanation. you haven't added anything new..

Comment: Yes I'm little bit late to answer trying to explain both option  :)

Comment: np, you have answered correctly, so upvote is yours :)